# Can I draw State-Transition diagrams in JSF2 Web App?

Tags: java, graph, jsf-2, state, diagram

I'm looking for a way to draw state-transition diagrams in my JSF2 project.
I would like to be able to load state and transition data and transform them in a graph that can be displayed on my web page.

I haven't found a way to do that yet. Charts available with Primefaces or MyFaces projects (I'm using the 1st one) are dedicated to statistics. In addition, it's probably possible to do that in javascript but I didn't found any example of that in the Google's API's for example.

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Clément

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there are components that display graphs using plain html, but you might look for a library that generates an image which you can display in your page. That library wouldn't necessarily be JSF specific though.

Edit: maybe [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/index.html) might be of interest for you.
In addition [PrimeFaces' dynaImage](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dynamicImage.jsf) might help you with displaying the generated graph image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer.
I will considerate the 2nd option which seems to be good.

Just one additional question: have you ever seen a state-transition diagram drawn with classical graphics Java API's (like Swing, etc.)?

Comment: I've seen some other graphs being drawn in plain Swing/Java2D and did that myself too. It's certainly doable but most of the time not worth the hassle. You're better off using a library for that. For Swing [JGraphT](http://www.jgrapht.org) might be an option as well.

Comment: Just a little feedback about the previous comment.
It has been very helpful to me. Combine JUNG API and PrimeFaces' dynaimage is the right solution.

Thanks a lot Thomas.